# Position for array

Tags: symbolic, list-manipulation

how does `Position`work for array? In particular if i have something like this:

```
m = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0};
Position[m, 1]
```

i obtain

```
{{1}, {6}, {8}}
```

If i consider an array with the same elements:

```
Position[Arraym,1]
```

i receive

```
{}
```

So if i have the same elements organized in array form how could i do ? Because my aim is to find the indices of nonzero elements of an array.

Comment: What is the difference between the list `m` and an array for you? Please give an example of what `Arraym` could be.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I presume by array you mean a matrix, which Mathematica represents as a `List` of lists, nested as deep as the number of dimensions of the matrix.  `Position` check only the top level of the nested lists, unless told to look deeper.  Review the documentation for the third argument of `Position`.

Comment: @C.E. I have an array populated through a for. I post the pseudocode :

Comment: @C.E. I have an array populated through a for , i don't post it because is full of subscripts. I've found that if i do ` Position[Array[MyArray,11],0` gives the correct result on the contrary `Position[MyArray,0]` gives blank brackets.  what you say?

Comment: For us, lists and arrays are exactly the same thing. `m` in your example is an array/list. So when you say that it works for `m` but it doesn't work for an array, that makes no sense to me. Also, I can't understand you new example because I can't know what the difference between `Array[MyArray,11]` and `MyArray` is unless I know how `MyArray` is defined.

Comment: @C.E. what can i tell you my friend, in this way position works in the other not.

Comment: You can give me a "minimal working example" (MWE) for the problem. That is, you can say: "This is how I define `m`, this is how I define `arraym`. I now expect `Position[m, 0]` and `Position[arraym, 0]` to be the same, but they're not. Why?" What's missing is your definition for `Arraym`.

Comment: @C.E.  `(*Other stuff*)
Array[MyArray, 10, 0];
For[t = 1, t <= Length[ListaCCC], t++,
 For[q = 0, q <= 9, q++,
  If[(D[ListaCCC[[t]], Subscript[x, q]]*
      Subscript[x, q] /ListaCCC[[t]]) == 1, MyArray[q] = 1, 
   MyArray[q] = 0]
  
  ] ]`

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you have told me, I can now guess what the problem is. Your question is the following:

```
list = {1, 2, 1, 3};
Position[list, 1]
```

returns `{{1},{3}}`. On the other hand,

```
list[1] = 1
list[2] = 2
list[3] = 1
list[4] = 2
Position[list, 1]
```

gives just `{}`, while you expected it to be the same thing. If this is the case then you have a lot to learn about Mathematica (which is OK, we all had to start somewhere), because that is not at all how it works.

Answering this question in this format is difficult because it would require me to go cover a lot of material. I recommend that you start with the following three texts instead:

- [Values for Symbols](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ValuesForSymbols.html)
- [Defining Variables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningVariables.html)
- [Defining Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html)

If you read these then you will understand that the corresponding concept of an array in Mathematica is a list and that it is not manipulated like this:

```
list[1] = 1
list[2] = 2
list[3] = 1
list[4] = 2
```

What you would have to do is this:

```
list = ConstantArray[0, 4];
list[[1]] = 1;
list[[2]] = 2;
list[[3]] = 1;
list[[4]] = 2;
Position[list, 1]
```

This code will give you `{{1}, {3}}`. The assignment `list[1] = 1` is also allowed but it does something else than what you think it does. (In short: `list` is now a function which takes as its input either 1, 2, 3, or 4 and outputs either 1 or 2.)